# Launch.json - Wait for first debugger to load, then execute second

Tags: reactjs, electron, vscode-debugger

I'm pretty new to debugging like this (I'm coming from a .NET background in VS where you pretty much have nothing to worry about).

I'm having an Electron / React setup that I had a pretty hard time to setup in the first place but it works pretty fine now. (From what I read, I'm not alone)

I was fine using the "devTool" for chrome for a while until I required breakpoint and line by line debugging for more complex stuff where it becomes a pain.

I have this so far:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Electron: Main",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm.cmd",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run-script", "start"
            ],
            "port": 5858
        },
        {
            "name": "Electron: Renderer",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "windows": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
            }
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
      {
        "name": "Debug",
        "configurations": ["Electron: Main", "Electron: Renderer"]
      }
    ]
}
```

The two debugger configuration works perfect. If I trigger "Main", then wait for it to open and then trigger the "Renderer" to attach to chrome, it works just fine.

The issue is that I am human. I can't trigger the second one fast enough so If I have stuff I want to debug onload, then I can't.

The "Coumpound" I made is not trigger on time and trigger way too early (I guess when the debugger is attached). It gives me an error message saying it can't attach to said port (which is normal as it hasn't loaded yet.

Question is. How do I make it "wait" for the main to be ready. Is that even doable?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [the documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process#debugging-the-main-process)? Outside of VSCode, it appears you can run the `electron` command with an `--inspect=[port]` or `--inspect-brk=[port]` flag. Then, launch Chrome and visit `chrome://inspect` and select the launched Electron app.

It appears your `launch.json` might need to be updated a little bit, here's what [that page](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-vscode) (on debugging in VSCode) says it should be. I am noticing you are using `workspaceRoot` instead of `workspaceFolder`.

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Main Process",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
      "windows": {
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
      },
      "args" : ["."],
      "outputCapture": "std"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Debugging works. It's a little more special since I'm using react as well. I need to delay the attach to chrome until it's actually launched and ready to be attached. If I wait myself and launch the second debug, it works.